RegionMeasure and Area give incorrect result for ImplicitRegion
Bug introduced in version 13 and persist to version 14.1 .
RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && y >= 2*x, {x, y}]] as well as Area gives finite answer, but the region is infinite.
It works fine if y>=2*x is removed.
ANOTHER EXAMPLE.
RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[(5/4)*Pi <= x <= (3/2)*Pi && 5*Sin[x] <= y <= 5*Cos[x], {x, y}]] outputs 0, when in fact it is nonzero.

The Area certainly should be logarithmically infinite.  The simpler region, ImplicitRegion[y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && y >= 3, {x, y}]. has the same problem.  Looks like a bug to me.

Yes, this is a bug.  We may test the case when  x>0,y>0,Clear[reg1,reg2]; reg1 =   ImplicitRegion[   y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && y >= 2*x && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]; reg2 = ImplicitRegion[   y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && y <= 2*x && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}];  RegionMeasure@reg1 + RegionMeasure@reg2 // Simplify the result is 0, obvious is wrong.

I have submitted this bug to Wolfram, Inc.

I have test the version 11.3, 12.2 and 12.3, all them get the result $\infty$ but version 13.3.1 get the wrong result.

Wolfram, Inc. has confirmed that this is a bug and forwarded it to the developers.

The another example is not a bug. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/309218/72111

Can you explain why the measure equals zero?


This is a bug. We get the right result ∞ in version 12.2.



confirm the bug.
For the convenience we assume that {x,y}>0. We can rewrite such region as

Clear[reg];
reg[k1_, k2_] := 
  ImplicitRegion[{1 <= x*y <= 4, k1 <= y/x <= k2, x > 0, y > 0}, {x, 
    y}];
Assuming[c > 2, RegionMeasure[reg[2, c], 2]] // FullSimplify


3/2 Log[c/2]

when $c\to+\infty$ is obvious tend to $+\infty$.

Or

Assuming[k > 2, 
  RegionMeasure[
   ImplicitRegion[y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && k*x >= y >= 2*x, {x, y}], 
   2]] // FullSimplify


3/2 Log[k/2]


By the change of variables, we can calculate the area of such region, that is we set
\begin{align} 
\begin{cases}u=x y \\
             v=\frac{y}{x}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Clear[expr, jacobian]; 
expr = {x, y} /. 
  FullSimplify[
    Assuming[ u > 0 && v > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, 
     Solve[{u == x*y, v == y/x}, {x, y}]], u > 0 && v > 0][[1]]
jacobian = 
 Simplify[Abs@Det@Grad[expr, {u, v}], 
  Assumptions -> {u > 0 && v > 0}]
int[k1_, k2_] = 
 Integrate[jacobian, {u, 1, 4}, {v, k1, k2}, 
   Assumptions -> {0 < k1 < k2}] // FullSimplify


3/2 Log[k2/k1]

which confirm the result.

3/2 Log[k2/k1] when $k_1=2$ and $k_2 \to \infty$,the result is  $+\infty$

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  y <= 4/x && y >= 1/x && k*x >= y >= 2 x, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  Epilog -> {HalfLine[{0, 0}, {1, 2}], Red, 
    HalfLine[{0, 0}, {1, k}]}], {k, 2, 100}]



For the new example,we can set GenerateConditions -> All as in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/309218/72111

RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[(5/4)*Pi <= x <= (3/2)*Pi && 5*Sin[x] <= y <= 5*Cos[x], {x, y}],GenerateConditions -> All]


